# Postfix multi instance with separate SASLDB for each instance

Tags: postfix, sasl, saslauthd

I configured postfix with multiple instances (postmulti), each instance has your own IP address and it´s working great, but I need each instance uses it´s own sasldb2 file to authenticate users.

The problem I am consolidating 35 postfix dedicated VMs in 1 vm with postmult, but this 35 instances is for a authenticated relay and all has the same username "auth@smtp.com.br" with different passwords and I do not want to force customers to change their usernames, I like to make this change as transparent possible to final users.

Actually, the /var/spool/postfix/etc/sasldb2 is shared between instances, I really need each instance works with your own db like /var/spool/postfix-22/sasldb

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can set a separate `smtpd_sasl_path` for each Postfix instance then you could point each instance to a separate SASL configuration file and then within that you can set a different `sasldb_path`. For example, in Postfix:

```
smtpd_sasl_path = instance1
```

That means the SASL library will look for the configuration in `/etc/sasl2/instance1.conf` (directory may vary) instead of the default `/etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf`, which can then contain:

```
pwcheck_method: auxprop
auxprop_plugin: sasldb
mech_list: ...
sasldb_path: /path/to/instance-specific/sasldb
```

Would that work?